# Text file formatting is changed after sending it using mailx

Tags: bash, formatting, mailx

I'm sending the below file via mailx like this:

cat file | mailx -s "test" -r address address

cat file:

```
+----------+------+--------+
|   name   | rank | gender |
+----------+------+--------+
|  Jacob   |  1   |  boy   |
+----------+------+--------+
```

When I receive it in the message body it looks like:

```
+----------+------+--------+
|   name       | rank | gender |
+----------+------+--------+
|  Jacob     |  1   |  boy   |
+----------+------+--------+
```

Comment: Did you check whether the white space in `file` consists really of spaces only, or whether there are other characters present, for instance tabs?

Comment: No tabs or other characters, only spaces and new line

Comment: If you look at the raw message on the receiver's side, do you see the inserted spaces too?

Comment: I don't understand the question... If you mean the message in outlook after I received it, yes there I see the extra spaces

Comment: You see only, what outlook PRESENTS you. This is not necessarily the same as what is in the message. Outlook might insert or delete spaces if it is in the mood to do saw. Hence you have to look at the raw message to see, whether the problem is really in the mail, or rather on the receiver's end.

Comment: I'm sure that the problem is in outlook which insert or delete spaces. I'm asking what can be done in this case when I need to send a table to list of people and the table itself is very beautiful and formatted and they receive it with such a bad formatting

Comment: Honestly, ask the receiver to use a reasonable mail reader. I guess one can configure Outlook not to fiddle around with plain text, but of course you have no control over what the receivers of your mail are doing. You could at least verify (for the safe side), that the outgoing mail is of content-type text/plain. You **could** also decide to send the email as text/html (which means that you would have to generate a HTML table), but doing this just because someone is using a broken mail reader, looks like overkill to me.